# 20+ backup directories, I'd like to dedupe all files to 1 "master directory"

Tags: linux, backup, directory-structure, software-rec, deduplication

As the title suggests, I have inherited a file structure where there are about 30 "complete or partial backups" of a fileserver full of text files.  This obviously makes no sense, and I'd like to run a dedupe on this that produces one "master directory" which contains all the unique files from all the backups.  (At which point I can then delete all the backups, and not actually LOSE anything).

Yes, I realize file CHANGES are an issue, and in that case I'd like to keep the most recent file.

I've looked through rdupes, and jdupes, and robinhood, and not really seen options to do what I need.  Did I miss it?  Is there something better that I haven't seen?

Comment: This might turn out to be a very bad idea. Files are frequently inter-dependent, so the newest versions of two or more may not be compatible. Files can be renamed, merged or split. Some may have been deleted since the older backups, and you risk restoring obsolete code or data. The latest version of a source may not even be production code -- just a branch with temporary debug.

Comment: Furthermore, the absence of a file may be important to a working installation

Comment: IMO what would make more sense is to link non-zero sized identical files. You'll save your disk space but otherwise leave all your backups intact

Comment: Guys, I know what I'm asking sounds bad, and like I'm making a mistake.  I assure you I'm not, and I know what I'm doing.  (These are collections of text files only.  No system files, or binary files).

So, ignoring any reservations about it, Do you know of any way to DO it?

Comment: @waltinator please stop leaving these terse, rude, and unhelpful comments that just tell people to read the manual. They are not helpful, they are not nice and they are not welcome. We have been through this several times now. Stop it! Either post an answer explaining the issue (where you are welcome to also mention the man page), or downvote and walk away. But just leaving "read man foo" comments is condescending, unhelpful and rude.

Comment: If the filename is a unique and consistent identifer....Is there a reason you don't simple (e.g.) `mv -f backup-2022-oct/* backup-master/ ; mv -f backup-2022-nov/* backup-master/ ; ....` (or ordered by date descending with noclobber).

Comment: @symcbean  The only reason I'm not doing it that way is because I didn't think about it.  The file structure under each backup directory is the same, so I should be able to skip the sorting, right? And if I want the latest version to be the official version, I can just process the directories oldest to newest without the "noclobber", right?

Comment: That would be how I would do it, yes.